# Build npm package with desired file structure

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have created a simple typescript project to export ENUMS, I successfully compile the project. tsconfig.json and package.json below.
I use the npm command to pack it and npm publish it also. I install the same package to a new project and I import the same with the code

```
import Numbers = require('@hk18/export/dist');
```

while I want to be like

```
import Numbers = require('@hk18/export');
```

It is including the dest folder in the package why so ?

```
{   "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true   },   "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "index.ts"   ] }

___________________________________________________________

{   "name": "@hk18/export",   "version": "2.0.0",   "description": "test project to create npm package",   "main": "index.js",   "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "lint": "tslint --project \"./tsconfig.json\"",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec",
    "docs": "typedoc --out docs src",
    "gh-pages": "rimraf docs && npm run docs && gh-pages -d docs"   },   "author": "HK",   "license": "ISC", }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [package.json is missing a `types` entry](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/library.html). It should match your `main` entry. Also your main should point to the `dist` folder as well.

## Fixed Version

```
"main": "./dist/index.js",
"types" : "./dist/index.d.ts",
```